# I got this error :"No active account found with the given credentials" when i try to make jwt request

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm trying to build a Rest Api Using Django.For the authentication i decide to use JWT but when i make a request using Postman, i got this error :

"detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"

I don't Know why i got this error.

this is my settings file

```
"""
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    "rest_framework",
    "api",
]


 
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication' ,
    ),
    # ...
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]



# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL="api.CustomUser"
```

The models file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("L'adresse email doit être définie.")
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)
        user.set_password('nouveau_mot_de_passe')
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and the serializers file

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model=CustomUser
        fields="__all__"
```

the credentials that i use to test Api are correct and exist in my Users database.Please help me